# Flex split string by dot is not working

Tags: regex, apache-flex

I have a textbox in flex in which I am trying to split the amount entered by the user. Code is something like:

```
var splitAmount:Array = toAmountLocal.split("\\.");
```

tried with different options with dot(.) but nothing is working, every time its returning `splitAmount.length` as 1 only.

Comment: Should it not be `toAmountLocal.split("\.")`

Comment: what amount are you entering in the textbox..this may be the issue about the input itself

Comment: what is toAmountLocal? its an id for your textbox or variable where you are storing user entered string? if it is ID than you have to modify it as toAmountLocal.text.split(".");

Comment: toAmountLocal is a local variable which contains value like "123.45678"

Comment: If it is local variable and value is "123.45678" than splitAmount.length will be 1, if it is "123.45.6.78" than splitAmount.length will be 3 means what you are getting is correct.

Comment: in case of "123.45.6.78" is also returning length = 1.

Comment: Please find below comment which will help you to solve your problem: - if user is entering value your local variable should be updated

Comment: It doesnt need to have escape characters.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a String as an argument for the `split` method, you don't have to escape anything; just do:

```
toAmountLocal.split(".");
```

However if you wish to use a regular expression as an argument, then you will have to escape the dot with just one backslash, like this:

```
toAmountLocal.split(/\./);
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code may help you: i have added comment what you are missing in logic.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600"
               creationComplete="init()">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.controls.Alert;

            [Bindable]
            private var toAmountLocal:String = "123.45.6.78";

            private function onClickHandler():void
            {
                //if user is entering value your local variable should be updated.
                toAmountLocal = inputID.text;
                var splitAmount:Array = toAmountLocal.split('.');
                Alert.show(splitAmount.length.toString())
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>

    <s:layout>
        <s:VerticalLayout/>
    </s:layout>

    <s:TextInput id="inputID" text="{toAmountLocal}"/>
    <s:Button label="Split" click="onClickHandler()"/>

</s:Application>
```